# react mapping state to list items

Tags: reactjs, mapping

i'm having trouble mapping my state into a series of list items. For some reason the dom renders the mapped list then all of a sudden gives the error: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

I'm missing something incredibly obvious but can't find it! ;(

```
 state={
    allCards: '',
    currentDeck: [
      {
        name: 'card1',
        color: 'black',
      },
      {
        name: 'card2',
        color: 'blue',
      },
      {
        name: 'card3',
        color: 'red',
      }
    ],
    blue: 1,
    black: 1,
    white: 1,
    green: 1,
    red: 1
  }
```

```
<div className="currentD">
              <h4>Deck List</h4>
              <ul>
              {
                  this.state.currentDeck.map((card)=>{
                    return(
                      <li>{card.name}</li>
                    )
                  })
              }
              </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: there is no problem in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this- your code is working - https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-ellis-uw5rd

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    allCards: "",
    currentDeck: [
      {
        name: "card1",
        color: "black"
      },
      {
        name: "card2",
        color: "blue"
      },
      {
        name: "card3",
        color: "red"
      }
    ],
    blue: 1,
    black: 1,
    white: 1,
    green: 1,
    red: 1
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ul>
          {this.state.currentDeck.map((card, index) => (
            <li key={index}>
              {card.name}-{card.color}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @monsterpiece check this

Comment: thanks! i was setting my const to this.state.currentDeck instead of this.state and I think I was calling it incorrectly